# Which hash algorithm for unique index on a complete database row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hash

I want to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` on a `mysql` database to batch insert large datasets.

To skip already existing rows (the rows should be unique by *all* columns, which are approx 20), I want to calculate a `hash` and add a `unique index` on it. Thereby the load will skip already existing entries.

I would want to use `GENERATED COLUMNS`:

```
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (md5(concat('column1', 'column2', ... 'columnN'))) STORED NOT NULL;
```

But as the files to load are prepared by a `java` tool, I could likely add any hashing algorithm instead of calculating in in the db.

Question: which hash algorithm would be best with regards to performance and 
collision?

`md5, sha-1, sha-2, sha-256`?

Sample size is about 100 mio rows.

Comment: We use md5 for performance and have not seen collision so far but that said it depends on the quantity of your data

Comment: Sample size is about 100 mio rows.

Comment: Are collisions an absolute no-go or allowed? What would you do if you would get a collision?

Comment: Well I could probably not detect collisions explicit, as `LOAD DATA` command just ignores rows that are duplicate with regards to a `unique index`. But collisions are *just* unwanted, not a no-go. It's for cache data that are renewed every 24h and meanwhile updated incremental. But many applications rely on that cachedata, so I'm trying to achieve the best results I could get without performance drawbacks.

Comment: `... the rows should be unique by all columns,` which implies  that **all** columns are part of a candidate key. Also:, for concat() to be effective, they should all be NOT NULL.

Comment: I don't have the time to write a full answer, but the following link has the information you are looking for: [Comparison of hash functions and performance benchmarks](http://greenrobot.org/essentials/features/performant-hash-functions-for-java/comparison-of-hash-functions/). See the linked PDF for details.

Comment: @wildplasser yes all columns are not null and so to say part of the candidate key. except I have >16 columns that's why I cannot just use a composite unique index.

Comment: @membersound my case 5 records, with out problems, but when you say 100 mil you might concider fnvj as MicSim link says. you might give it a try take some time but worth to know :)

Comment: What if I'd be just using a `VARCHAR(255)` as unique index, and the content being a concatenated string of all my columns, without any hash? Would that slow inserts down more than having a hash? (as said, I'd be only using the column for duplicate detection. Not for queries).

Comment: I tried that on a subset of 5 mio rows, where performance is equal. Only the db size is 3x, probably to the larger index. But still much better than inserting duplicates, thus I'll probably stick to creating my own "hash" by just using all db columns concatenated as unique-index. Plus: I'm on the safe side regarding collusion.